# How to add reference to Visual Studio .cu project?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cuda

I'm trying to use the ArrayFire library with my `.cu` project. The references dialogue box seems to be for CLR projects only.

ArrayFire's own documentation is very sparse, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Select your project and click on Properties

Select C/C++ --> General --> Add following to the "Additional Include Directories" $(AF_PATH)\include;

Select Linker --> General --> Add following to the "Additional Library Directories" $(AF_PATH)\lib;

Select Linker --> Input --> Add following to "Additional Dependencies" libaf.lib;libafGFX.lib;

Remember that the Licencse File has to be in your Project Folder of Visual Studio 2010 or you need to have a Internet connection to use ArraFire